# Resend account activation email

Tags: python, django

so I created a template where users can register on my site. After filling the registration form an activation email is sent to the users email address.

In case the user didn't receive an email I want to make it possible to resend the activation email. How do I do this?

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings

from .forms import UserSignUpForm
from .token_generator import account_activation_token


def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            email_subject = 'Activate Your Account'
            message = render_to_string('accounts/email_templates/account_activation.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(email_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()
            # TODO: resend activation email
            return HttpResponse('We have sent you an email, please confirm your email address to complete registration')
    else:
        form = UserSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form, 'project_name': settings.PROJECT_NAME})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, help_text='Required')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

**signup.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %}{{ project_name }}{% trans " Registration" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{% trans "Create account" %}</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Create your ' %}{{ project_name }}{% trans ' account' %}"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**token_generator.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six


class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) + six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )


account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

Comment: Put the whole logic to send email inside a single function with the user id and other relevant parameters, and use it to send email wherever you want

Comment: I thought about passing just the email from the signup form view to the next view where it says 'We have sent you an email, please confirm ...' and from there just resend the email with a button if needed. However I'm not quite sure how to trigger a python function from a html button press.Also I wonder if i can use the same account activation token or if I should use a new one.

Comment: No, you shouldn't use the same token... You can use a Django view to handle that. Trigger your button and send the request to the server via AJAX to call the view that will send the activation email.